# Should I define an empty class so that I can use it as a generic

Tags: java, generics, subclass

I have two classes:

1. `GroupRunner`
2. `GroupSwimmer`

They both extend another class: `AthleteResult`.

I would like to define another class, `GroupResult`, that performs methods on both `GroupRunner` and `GroupSwimmer`.

If I define `GroupResult` as follows:

```
public class GroupResult<T extends AthleteResult>
```

Then that would mean that `GroupResult` could also perform operations on `AthleteResult`. I don't want this, I want it to only perform operations on `GroupRunner` or `GroupSwimmer` (i.e., subclasses of `AthleteResult`). 
I can create another class in between `AthleteResult` and the two group classes which the two group classes will extend but since the two group classes don't have any shared methods, this class would be empty. For example:

```
public class Group extends AthleteResult
{}
```

Is this necessary? Or is there another way to limit the class `GroupResult` to only accept `GroupSwimmer` or `GroupRunner`?

Comment: If they have no methods in common, the only common methods would be those in AthleteResult.  As such why is is it invalid for an AthleteResult to be passed in?

Comment: I made up the names of the classes for the example so it's hard to follow the logic, but an AthleteResult is not a Group. A Group has certain distinguishing features but none that are shared.

Comment: What is in the class Athlete result that you don't want to perform operations on? Is it possible to make it an interface instead?

Comment: @theyuv "but an AthleteResult is not a Group" but in your question "`Group extends AthleteResult`" which would mean that it *is*. And what do you mean by "Accept"? I think there is some fundamental misunderstanding. Seems like you maybe want two top level classes `Group` and `Result` or something but are making them extend from each other in ways that don't make sense.

Comment: "Group extends AthleteResult" means a Group is an AthleteResult (not vice versa)

Answer (score 3):

An interface might be a better idea. Then expose the methods you want.

```
public interface Group


public class GroupResult<T extends Group>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you suggesting that the interface Group be empty? What do you mean by "Then expose the methods you want"?

Comment: Depends on how you want to go about this. If its empty, then it will act simply as a marker interface much like the way `Serializeable` works. However, I would recommend that you expose the common methods that you would like operate on. This way, your `GroupResult` class operates on the `Group` interface and not the actual implementation of either `GroupRunner` or `GroupSwimmer`

Comment: By "expose the common methods" do you mean declare them in the Group interface? Which methods would I be declaring there? The methods that I intended to place in the GroupResult class?

Comment: Yes, put them in the `Group` interface. The methods would be the ones that are common to both `GroupRunner` and `GroupSwimmer` that you need to perform your operations in the `GroupResult` class. For example, say both classes have a `public int getAge()` method (note that this could even be inherited from `AthleteResult`). And you need this method to group them, then put `getAge()` in the interface. This should achieve the encapsulation you desire.

Comment: The two classes GroupRunner and GroupSwimmer do not have any shared methods.

Comment: Then I see no benefit of using generics, your better off with some sort of dependency injection. Otherwise, your going to have to do casts, which in my opinion with what you stated, would be poor code design.

Comment: As stated in the question, the purpose is so that I can limit the methods performed in another class to solely these two classes (rather than being able to perform it on all AthleteResult Objects). As you said, Serializable seems to be an example of this.

Comment: Yes, but if you do that approach, you will have to test for class type and do casts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80908/discussion-between-theyuv-and-user489041).